# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, php-7.3

I want to display data from multiple table to one view, first table is `Transaction_in` and second table is `Transaction_in_detail` but beside those two other table are involved.

**This is Transcation_in Controller**

```
class Transactions_inController extends Controller
{
public function show($id)
    {
        $supplierList = Supplier::where('id', 'nama')->first();
        $transactionin = Transaction_in::where('id', $id)->first();
        $deviceTypeList = DeviceType::where('id', 'nama_tipe_device')->first();
        $deviceBrandList = DeviceBrand::where('id', 'nama_brand_device')->first();
        $transactionindetail = Transaction_in_detail::where('id', 'Transansaction_in_id')->first();
        //return view('transactionsin.show', compact('supplierList', 'transactionsin', 'deviceTypeList', 'deviceBrandList', 'transactionindetail'));
        return view('transactionsin.show')->with('transactionsin', $transactionin);
        return view('transactionsin.show')->with('transactionsindetail', $transactionindetail);   
    }
}
```

**Transaction_in Model**

```
class Transaction_in extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function get_suppliers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class, 'Supplier_id');
    }
    public function get_devicetypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeviceType::class, 'DeviceType_id');
    }
    public function get_devicebrands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeviceBrand::class, 'DeviceBrand_id');
    }
    public function get_transactionindetail()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Transaction_in_detail::class, 'Transaction_in_id');
    }
}
```

**Transaction_in_detail Model**

```
class Transaction_in_detail extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function get_transction_in_id()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Transaction_in::class, 'Transaction_in_id');
    }
    public function get_devicetypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeviceType::class, 'DeviceType_id');
    }
    public function get_devicebrands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeviceBrand::class, 'DeviceBrand_id');
    }
}
```

I want to display data from `Transaction_in_detail` table to `Transaction_in` Controller, but i have this error

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\resources\views\transactionsin\show.blade.php)

and this is `transactionsin.show` code https://hastebin.com/ilewesucej.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
You are using `first()` method which returns a single **object** , not array. Instead of returning a collection of models, `first()` method returns a single model instance. Rewrite your code as following -

```
$transactionin = Transaction_in::where('id', $id)->get();
```

For reference, [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

**2.**
You don't have to return view and variables twice. Return once as following -

```
return view('transactionsin.show',compact('transactionsin','transactionsindetail'));
```

Answer (score 2):

What does your table setup look like, specifically what is the relationship between `Transaction_in` and `Transaction_in_detail`? You have a One To Many relationship given in `Transaction_in_detail::get_transaction_in_id` and a Many to Many relationship given in `Transaction_in::get_transactionindetail`.

The `belongsToMany` relationship is for Many to Many relationships with a pivot table. Maybe this is supposed to be `hasMany` instead?

Start by clarifying that relationship correctly. See [the docs on relationships in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships). Then you can pull the correct data.

---

Are you trying to get ONE `Transaction_in` instance with the id `$id`? In that case, no, you can't iterate over it. Maybe you're trying for something like this?

```
$transactionin = Transaction_in::find($id);
$transactionindetail = $transactionin->get_transactionindetail;

// $transactionindetail will now be a `Collection` which implements `Countable`.
```

---

Also note that you're (and some of the other answers) are mixing up `transactionsin` and `transactionin` (without the 's').

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return **view two times**. use compact for set multiple variable.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $supplierList = Supplier::where('id', 'nama')->first();
    $transactionin = Transaction_in::where('id', $id)->first();
    $deviceTypeList = DeviceType::where('id', 'nama_tipe_device')->first();
    $deviceBrandList = DeviceBrand::where('id', 'nama_brand_device')->first();
    $transactionindetail = Transaction_in_detail::where('id', 'Transansaction_in_id')->first();
    //return view('transactionsin.show', compact('supplierList', 'transactionsin', 'deviceTypeList', 'deviceBrandList', 'transactionindetail'));
    return view('transactionsin.show',compact('transactionsin','transactionsindetail'));
}
```

In blade file check with **empty** condition.

```
@if (!empty($transactionsin))
    <div class="tale-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead align="center">
                <tr class="table-primary">
                    <th>Tipe Perangkat</th>
                    <th>Brand Perangkat</th>
                    <th>Spesifikasi</th>
                    <th>Jumlah</th>
                    <th>Harga</th>
                    <th>Total Harga</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $transactionin->get_devicetypes->nama_tipe_device }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transactionin->get_devicebrands->nama_brand_device }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transactionin->get_transactionindetail->spek_device }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transactionin->get_transactionindetail->harga_device }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transactionin->get_transactionindetail->jumlah_device }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transactionin->get_transactionindetail->total_harga_device }}</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
@else
    <h6>No Data Found</h6>
@endif
```

Comment: your answer does remove the answer but i get another error `Trying to get property 'get_devicetypes' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\resources\views\transactionsin\show.blade.php)`  the `devicetype` is saved in `Transaction_in_detail` not `Transaction_in` here is the migration table https://hastebin.com/ocosonuyal.php

Comment: This error is from `{{ $tdin->get_devicetypes->nama_tipe_device }}` this line do `Transaction_in` have `get_devicebrands` function?

Comment: You can remove it as using `ternary operator` do that code as `{{ $tdin->get_devicetypes->nama_tipe_device ?? '' }}`

Comment: i change the `transactionsin` to `transactionsindetail` inside `if..else` now i think may be work but it gives me this error `Cannot end a section without first starting one. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\resources\views\transactionsin\show.blade.php)`

Comment: Remove foreach loop you're getting only first record though. I've edited my answer please check it.

Comment: Im sorry to bother you again but it gives me another error https://hastebin.com/uliwemujos.sql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201935/discussion-between-dilip-hirapara-and-aditya).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make object countable you have to use `$object->count()`in your case `$transactionin->count()`